# AFNetworking+UIImageView placeholder image shows up, but not URL image

Tags: ios, ios5, uiimageview, afnetworking

I'm trying to use the AFNetworking UIImageView call to load images from a URL as shown below:

```
[self.image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:feed.imageURL] placeholderImage:     [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo"]];
```

The placeholder image always shows up, but the actual image from "feed.imageURL" never does. I've verified that the URL is actually correct.  I even hardcoded it to make sure, and still nothing.

My basic app setup is a tab controller...and in viewDidLoad, I call a method "fetchFeed" which performs the HTTP request to gather my JSON data.

My request block looks like:

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation
                                    JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                     success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse   *response, id JSON) {
                                         [self parseDictionary:JSON];
                                         isLoading = NO;
                                         [self.tableView reloadData];

                                         } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request,   NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
                                             NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                                             [self showNetworkError];
                                             isLoading = NO;
                                             [self.tableView reloadData];
                                         }];
operation.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript", @"text/html", nil];
[queue addOperation:operation];
```

Comment: Are your images within UITableViewCells?  Are you calling `setImageWithURL` in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method?

Comment: Yes, to both of your questions.

Comment: Could you include the code you use to set the remote images, in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`?

Comment: Mattt, that code is included.  It's at the top of my post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out the server I was requesting the image from was sending `content-type "image/jpg"` and by default AFNetworking does not support this file type.

I changed the class method in AFImageRequestOperation to look like:

```
+ (NSSet *)defaultAcceptableContentTypes {
return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"image/tiff", @"image/jpeg", @"image/gif", @"image/png", @"image/ico", @"image/x-icon" @"image/bmp", @"image/x-bmp", @"image/x-xbitmap", @"image/x-win-bitmap", @"image/jpg", nil];
}
```

and it fixed my problem.

Comment: You made my day! For AFNetworking 2.0 it's `self.acceptableContentTypes = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:@"image/tiff", @"image/jpeg", @"image/jpg", @"image/gif", @"image/png", @"image/ico", @"image/x-icon", @"image/bmp", @"image/x-bmp", @"image/x-xbitmap", @"image/x-win-bitmap", nil];` in AFURLResponseSerialization.m

Comment: How should I use this ? , I think have the same problem ! [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766499/having-issue-with-getting-image-from-server)

Answer (score 2):

You can manage to accept what `content-type` you want with this library simply changing the `request` like this:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:yourURL];
[request addValue:@"image/*" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
```

And call the AFNetworking method:

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation
                                     JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                     success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse   *response, id JSON) {
                                     } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request,   NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
                                     }];
```

This way you will be able to override the `content-type` **without** changing the library.

Answer (score 2):

AFNetworking doesn't support **image/jpg MIME TYPE** by default.

You can support it without modifying the AFNetworking Library

```
[AFImageRequestOperation addAcceptableContentType:@"image/jpg"];
```

Answer (score 0):

All operations that manipulate the UI must be performed on the main thread.  So you may need to use 'performSelectorOnMainThread:' when reloading your tableview data in the completion block.

```
[self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO]
```

Comment: Good suggestion Jonkroll, didn't help my cause though.

Comment: FWIW, all AFNetworking callback blocks execute on the main thread by default already.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but it turned out that I was passing a URL which contained spaces in it. When I properly encoded the URL using `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` the images now load.